# Error uploading a file using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to upload a file (picture) to the server using `Retrofit 2`. I'm following that [tutorial](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server) which seems pretty easy at first, but didn't work in my case...

When I call the API function, i'm always getting this error:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:190)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:166)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
W/System.err:     at com.plante.android.cobalt.fragment.FragmentIncidentPlan.uploadFile(FragmentIncidentPlan.java:575)
```

*Here is my API call:*

```
@Multipart
@POST(Constants.URL_UPLOAD)
Call<ResponseBody> upload(@Part RequestBody description,
                          @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

*Here is the method I use to upload a file:*

```
private void uploadFile(String path) {
    // create upload service client

    // use the FileUtils to get the actual file by uri
    File file = new File(path);
    Log.e(TAG, file.getAbsolutePath());

    // create RequestBody instance from file
    RequestBody requestFile =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    MultipartBody.Part body =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.getName(), requestFile);

    // add another part within the multipart request
    String descriptionString = "hello, this is description speaking";
    RequestBody description =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), descriptionString);

    // finally, execute the request
    Call<ResponseBody> call = cobaltServices.upload(description, body);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call,
                               Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.v("Upload", "success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Upload error:", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Check line 575 of `FragmentIncidentPlan.java` you're using an array that goes out of it's bounds.

Comment: @Exaqt That line is in my question actually :    Call<ResponseBody> call = cobaltServices.upload(description, body);

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I fix my issue using this link : https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1063#issuecomment-145920568

This is the solution of the problem:

```
@Multipart
@POST ("/api/Events/editevent")
Call<Event> editEvent (@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params);
```

I call it by following way.

```
Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Id", AZUtils.toRequestBody(eventId));
map.put("Name", AZUtils.toRequestBody(titleView.getValue()));

if (imageUri != null) {
      File file = new File(imageUri.getPath());
      RequestBody fileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), file);
      map.put("file\"; filename=\"pp.png\"", fileBody);
}

Call<Event> call = api.editEvent(map);
call.enqueue(new Callback<Event>() { }
```

The method toRequestBody just converts String into RequestBody

```
public static RequestBody toRequestBody (String value) {
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), value);
    return body ;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

The Exceptions says that the first `@Part` doesn't needs a name in the annotation.

```
@Multipart
@POST(Constants.URL_UPLOAD)
Call<ResponseBody> upload(@Part RequestBody description,
                          @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

Comment: `@Part parameters using the MultipartBody.Part must not include a part name in the annotation.` says that you shouldn't use a name. So it should be `@Part` instead of `@Part("description")`

Comment: Note that after `@Part` and before `MultipartBody.Part` there is no parameter.